# Vue.js in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, vue.js

### Vue.js in Chrome extension

Hi! I'm trying to make a Chrome extension using Vue.js but when I write

```
<input v-model="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
```

Chrome removes the v-model-part of the code and makes it

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Are you sure it's Chrome and not vue.js?

Comment: To use Vue and Vuetify without build/bundler/transformer tools see
https://stackoverflow.com/q/77557516/8583692

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have you csp version (Vue.js v1)

CSP-compliant build

Some environments, such as Google Chrome Apps, enforces Content Security Policy (CSP) and does not allow the use of new Function() for evaluating expressions. In these cases you can use the CSP-compliant build instead.

(Vue.js v1) http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#CSP-compliant-build

```
npm install vue@csp --save

"dependencies": {
  "vue": "1.0.26-csp"
}
```

New version (Vue.js v2) https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CSP-environments

Some environments, such as Google Chrome Apps, enforce Content Security Policy (CSP), which prohibits the use of new Function() for evaluating expressions. The standalone build depends on this feature to compile templates, so is unusable in these environments.

There is a solution however. When using Vue in a build system with Webpack + vue-loader or Browserify + vueify, your templates will be precompiled into render functions which work perfectly in CSP environments.

Comment: THANK YOU! I went through the guide multiple times but somehow missed that paragraph...

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out, would've taken me ages to figure this out. Enjoy some bounty.

Answer (score 19):

I guess you were using code like `new Vue(...)` in your implementation, as [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/87) said.

Please be aware [by default CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#restrictions) in chrome extension, [eval and related functions are disabled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSEval).

> Code like the following does not work:
>
> - `alert(eval("foo.bar.baz"));`
> - `window.setTimeout("alert('hi')", 10);`
> - `window.setInterval("alert('hi')", 10);`
> - **`new Function("return foo.bar.baz");`**

So the solution would be

### 1. Relaxing the default policy.

As per the description of [Evaluated JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-eval),

> The policy against eval() and its relatives like `setTimeout(String)`, `setInterval(String)`, and `new Function(String)` can be relaxed by adding `'unsafe-eval'` to your policy:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"`

However, the guide also mentions that,

> we strongly recommend against doing this. These functions are [notorious XSS attack vectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Default_CSP_restrictions).

### 2. Using CSP-compliant build.(Recommended)

As the [installation page of Vue.js](http://vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#CSP-compliant-build) said,

> Some environments, such as Google Chrome Apps, enforces Content Security Policy (CSP) and does not allow the use of `new Function()` for evaluating expressions. In these cases you can use the [CSP-compliant build](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/csp/dist) instead.